# BottomSheetDialogFragment In Tablet Landscape

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomsheetdialogfragment

It is possible to change the width of a BottomSheetDialogFragment (material design) width? In tablet landscape mode, the width is match_parent. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bottom sheets look great on phones. But when putting them on tablets,
> they feel stretched out, especially in landscape mode. It’s due to the
> high ratio between peek height vs full tablet width. Details matter,
> and we want our tablet users as happy as phone users. Let’s customize
> bottom sheet width for tablets.

**values-w820dp/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="bottom_sheet_width">600dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Fragment File**

```
public class PopupSettingsFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
  ...

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new CustomWidthBottomSheetDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
  }

  static class CustomWidthBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialog {
    public CustomWidthBottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int theme) {
      super(context, theme);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      int width = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_sheet_width);
      getWindow().setLayout(width > 0 ? width : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://www.hidroh.com/2016/06/17/bottom-sheet-everything/)

Comment: thank you for the answer, it works in Java, so I will try to convert that into Kotlin since I'm using that in my project.